# How to extend Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I would like to create an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project using Razor Pages.

My objective is to create a project that contains two categories of Razor Page:

- Standard category: this category contains all Razor Pages that will be shared across multiple project
- Custom category: this category contains all Razor Pages that are relative to the project.

Up to here is all ok, I create two subfolder inside "Pages" directory: Standard folder, Custom folder.
I populate standard and custom folders with all razor page I need in every project, where all the razor
pages contained inside Standard folderz are the same in all my project.

For example

Project A:

- /Pages

  - /Standard

    - /SectionA

      - PageA
      - PageB
  - /Custom

    - /SectionE

      - PageD

Project B:

- /Pages

  - /Standard

    - /SectionA

      - PageA
      - PageB
  - /Custom

    - /SectionP

      - PageK

Project C:

- /Pages

  - /Standard

    - /SectionA

      - PageA
      - PageB
  - /Custom

    - /SectionV

      - PageJ

Here born my problem: I would implement the possibility, inside every project, to extend a standard
razor page, maybe to rewrite some endpoint (for example I want to change the behaviour of "onGet" 
method) or create a new one (like "onGetMyCustomGet").

I know that the simpliest solution is to change the code inside the standard razor page, but I want
to avoid this because standard pages can be replaced with new versions. So, Standard Pages must be 
project-indipendent and open to extension.

My idea is to create a "fake" Razor page, inside "/Custom" category that extend the standard razor
PageModel and override all methods I need to reimplement.

**The problem is:** how can I return the standard
razor page cshtml instead the fakeRazorPage cshtml? Is it possible?

Here you will find a sample project https://github.com/Blackleones/RazorPageResearch feel free to send pull request if you want collaborate.

Other ideas are accepted if there are not solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to copy & paste the source code of Standard Pages everywhere. Simply create a separate Razor Class Library project and reference it in your Project A /Project B / Project C, and then you could custom anything as you like.

Let's say you create a new project `RazorResearch.Core` as the "standard" Page:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here's the directory structure of the `RazorResearch.Core` project:

```
└───Pages/
    └───SectionA/
        └───PageA.cshtml
        └───PageA.cshtml.cs
        └───PageB.cshtml
        └───PageB.cshtml.cs
└───RazorResearch.Core.csproj
```

And now reference this RazorLib :

```
dotnet add reference <path-to-the-RazorResearch.Core.csproj>
```

Now you could custom any page as you like. For example, to custom the standard `SectionA/PageA.cshtml`, simply create a new `Pages/SectionA/PageA.cshtml`file.

```
└───Pages/
    └───SectionA/
        └───PageA.cshtml
        └───PageA.cshtml.cs
    └───SectionE/
        └───PageD.cshtml
        └───PageD.cshtml.cs
    └───Shared/
    └─── ...
└───WebApplication3.csproj
```

Comment: thank you ItMinus, your solution almost completely solves my problem but remains a detail: I would like to extend PageModel behaviour without create another cshtml. What I mean is create another PageModel that custom the standard behaviour but the cshtml view remains the standard.

Using your solution I can extend PageModel behaviour but I lost cshtml standard, so the new cshtml page is empty.

What I would like to do is simulate the [Route("myRoute", Order = 1)] over controllers where only standard behaviour define the view to render

Comment: @LeonardoLurci I'm not sure where there's a way to do that. But since the `OnGet()/OnPost()` methods return an `IActionResult`, I think maybe we could return a `View(path_to_view)` or something else to get the standard view. I don't know whether it's possible.  Once I get back to my computer , I'll try it and if can make it work, I'll update you.

Comment: @LeonardoLurci I've tried but the most easy way I can figure out is to copy the same `.cshtml` view file if you want to reuse them.

Comment: I found another solution to customize a standard pageModel without recreate another .cshtml. please see "custom_no_RCL" branch. 
I create CustomPageA.cs class and inside PageA.cshtml I set @model CustomPageA so, when I call "/standard/PageA" the pageModel behind it is CustomPageA. In this way I can customize the pageModel behaviour without create another cshtml.

Comment: @LeonardoLurci But in that way you still need to copy and paste the "standard" pages to every project. What make it worse is when you have multiple "standard" pages & multiple projects.

Comment: Your solution with Razor Class Library is better and I prefer it, but for our project copy only a cs file is more cheap then have an RCL. Thanks very much for your help